# Trying to test if an input is odd or even

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

I'm trying to test if an input is odd or even. The program says that if the input is even keep going, until the input is odd. When it is odd, it stops the program. But the program isn't stopping. Has anyone any idea?

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (isEven()) {
        if (isEven()) {
            isEven();
        } else {
            System.out.println(" You added an odd number, done!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
public static boolean isEven(){
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    if (a%2 ==0){
        System.out.println("You added an even number, go on");
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Your `isEven` always returns `true` even for odd numbers.Also you are skipping numbers when calling `isEven` inside the loop.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `isEven()` enough times in your main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better *simplify* all of this, you don't need to call your method multiple times :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (writeAndCheckEven(Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()))) {
        System.out.println("You added an even number, go on");
    }

    System.out.println("You added an odd number, done!");
}

private static boolean writeAndCheckEven(int number) {
    return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

- you don't need to use a `return` if there is no more code after
- you can directly use the `scanner` in the parameter
- don't use both `while` and `if` it won't do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite this code, because code contains incorrect logic.
Correct code for your requirements:

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        if (isEven(number)) {
            System.out.println("You added an even number, go on");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" You added an odd number, done!");
            return;
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isEven(int number) {
    return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using scanner, please check first and 5 line. Try this code :)